# What are best practices for validating email addresses in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, nspredicate

I'm looking for the simplest and cleanest method for validating email (String) in Swift. In Objective-C I used this method, but if I rewrite it to Swift, I get an error 'Unable to parse the format string' when creating predicate.

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Comment: Please always post your code that is not working.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward. If you're having issues with your Swift conversion, if might be beneficial to see what you've actually tried.

This works for me:

```
func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(candidate)
}

validateEmail("test@google.com")     // true
validateEmail("invalid@@google.com") // false
```

Comment: Well the difference is only in how we insert the emailRegex into the predicate...

func isEmailValid(strEmail: String) -> Bool {
    var strEmailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    var predicateEmail = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES \(strEmailRegex)")
    
    return predicateEmail.evaluateWithObject(strEmail)
}

Comment: Right - that won't work because you haven't provided any format arguments to the `NSPredicate` initializer. You still need to use `%@` and pass it in via the varargs list at the end.

Comment: thanks! I get it now - i just needed to look at init function of NSPredicate a bit longer :)

Comment: Your regex does not consider that characters like !#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~ are allowed and addresses must not contain . as first / last character.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0 version**

```
func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: candidate)
}

validateEmail("test@google.com")     // true
validateEmail("invalid@@google.com") // false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension String
{
    func isEmail() -> Bool
    {
        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the NSDataDetector API. A lot of the answers here will not support characters like `'` which are allowed in email addresses.

```
extension String {
    var isEmail: Bool {
        let dataDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
        let firstMatch = dataDetector?.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count))
        return (firstMatch?.range.location != NSNotFound && firstMatch?.url?.scheme == "mailto")
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
"foo@bar.com".isEmail  // true
"foo.mc'doo@foo-bar.com".isEmail   // true
```

I have also used this regular expression which comes from the Android SDK which works well:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}\\@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25})+
```

Why Apple doesn't just include a method on String for email validation is a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the extension which is working for every email domain.

Ex.: `.com`, `.co.uk`, `.co.in`, etc.

```
extension String {

     func isValidEmail() -> Bool {

         let emailRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
         let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
         return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(self)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just going to throw in my two-cents here and hit you with a curve-ball:

Do you really want to validate your email address like that?

See this [blogpost](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) which suggests all you need to do to check an email is valid is check it has an `@` symbol, or at most an `@` followed at some point by a `.`:

`/.+@.+\..+/i`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5, Xcode 14 solution with `NSDataDetector`, patched for trailing space and double dot cases:

```
extension String {
    var isEmail: Bool {
        // patch for NSDataDetector edge cases
        guard !contains("..") &&
              !hasPrefix("mailto:") else { return false }
        
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: count)

        guard let dataDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue),
              let firstMatch = dataDetector.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion,
                                                                                                                                                       range: range),
              let url = firstMatch.url else { return false }

        
        let numberOfMatches = dataDetector.numberOfMatches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: range)

        return numberOfMatches == 1 &&
               firstMatch.range.location != NSNotFound &&
               url.scheme == "mailto" &&
               url.absoluteString.hasSuffix(self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      class func isValidEmail(email:String)-> Bool
      {
          let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
          var emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
          let result = emailTest!.evaluateWithObject(email)
          return result
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Craigs answer works and if someone is struggling to implement it, here it is with the textFieldDidEndEditing func calling it. (UITextFieldDelegate needed)

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    if validateEmail(emailAddress.text)
    {
        println("valid")
    }
    else
    {
        println("NOT valid")
    }
}

func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(candidate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 simply set:

```
extension String {
var isEmail: Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
 }
}
```

add

```
UITextFieldDelegate
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Usage:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    guard let validEmailAddress = yourTextFiled.text else { return }
    if !(validEmailAddress.isEmail) {
        //is invalid address
    } else {
       //is valid address
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func isValidEmail(testStr: String) -> Bool {
    print("valid Email-ID: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if isValidEmail(txt_EmailID.text!){
        print("Email is Valid")
    }else{
        print("Email is not valid")
    }
}

// creat done button outlet

@IBAction func btn_Done(sender: AnyObject) {
    validated()

}
```